# ProjectReference which consumes a Nuget package isn't included when building

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm building `ClassLibrary2` which has a Project reference to `ClassLibrary1`.
`ClassLibrary1` has a Nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json`.

[image]

But when building `ClassLibrary2`, the bin folder only contains `ClassLibrary1.dll` and `ClassLibrary2.dll`. How can I make it possible that `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is also copied into the bin folder of `ClassLibrary2`?

[image]

Comment: I see no code that uses anything from `ClassLibrary1`, so the DLL is not needed. Add a class in 1 and use it in 2, then it should copy over the DLL.

Comment: Indeed, when I use something from `ClassLibrary1` that uses `Newtonsoft.Json`, then it's included in my `ClassLibrary2` build... weird it isn't added in my real solution...

Answer (score 1):

If you were using an SDK-style project with `PackageReference`-style NuGet references, then the package references would be transitive; `ClassLibrary2` would automatically include the NuGet packages referenced by `ClassLibrary1`.

Since you're using the older project format, with `packages.config` NuGet references, those references are *not* transitive. Any NuGet reference you add to `ClassLibrary1` must also be added to `ClassLibrary2`.

[Identify the project format | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format)

For supported project types, there's a command-line tool you can install which will convert your projects to the new SDK style:

[hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017: Tooling for converting pre 2017 project to the new Visual Studio 2017 format](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017)

For new class libraries, it's usually simplest to start with the .NET Standard Class Library template, which uses the new project format by default.

*ASP.NET (non-Core) projects don't support the new format. There may be others, but I can't find a definitive list.*